# Deleting a locked file created with TempFile

Tags: windows, go, temporary-files, temporary-directory

I have a GUI (lxn/walk) app patcher that downloads a file via ftp, streams it to a temporary file and extracts the contents to update the local files. The remove file command is deferred.

This works unless the user exits the program while the file is downloading, then the file isn’t deleted.

I tried to fix this by doing a graceful exit by catching the signal and removing the file there. But unfortunately it throws an error that the file can’t be deleted because it is being used by another program. Which makes sense because the another program is actually itself still writing to the temporary file.

Now I’m stuck and don’t know what to do to make sure that the temporary file is automatically gone once the patcher is not running. How do I do that correctly?

The file could also be created as a normal file, not just a temp file. I would just like to ask too, where in windows is best to write a temporary file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I’m stuck and don’t know what to do to make sure that the temporary file is automatically gone once the patcher is not running. How do I do that correctly?

There are no guaranteed ways to accomplish this as many things beyond the control of the application can cause it to exit. A power failure or kernel panic due to some hardware issue can crash the machine or force it to be restarted.

A strategy that is in common use is to implement a check on program startup for the status of the previous run. Some applications create a lock file at start and remove it on graceful exit. If this lock file exists when the program is restarted, this means the previous run did not result in a clean exit, and the application can take any corrective action. The exact action to be taken depends on the nature of the application, some refuse to start, others give warnings to users.

> I would just like to ask too, where in windows is best to write a temporary file?

Each OS has its own location for temporary files. If you eliminate the `dir` argument to `TempFile`, it will create it in the appropriate location, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#TempFile):

> `TempFile` creates a new temporary file in the directory dir, opens the
>   file for reading and writing, and returns the resulting `*os.File`. The
>   filename is generated by taking pattern and adding a random string to
>   the end. If pattern includes a `"*"`, the random string replaces the
>   last `"*"`. **If dir is the empty string, `TempFile` uses the default
>   directory for temporary files (see `os.TempDir`).** Multiple programs
>   calling `TempFile` simultaneously will not choose the same file. The
>   caller can use `f.Name()` to find the pathname of the file. It is the
>   caller's responsibility to remove the file when no longer needed.

From [`os.TempDir`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#TempDir) we see the following:

> On Unix systems, it returns `$TMPDIR` if non-empty, else `/tmp`. On
>   Windows, it uses `GetTempPath`, returning the first non-empty value
>   from `%TMP%`, `%TEMP%`, `%USERPROFILE%`, or the Windows directory. On
>   Plan 9, it returns `/tmp`.
>
> The directory is neither guaranteed to exist nor have accessible
>   permissions.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add that yes, currently, I delete the TempFiles on startup. But lets say that the issue is just if the app is exited and not think about system shutdown/restart. Would there be a way? or still a no?

Comment: Barring extremes such as a kernel panic or power failure (which need to be addressed in other ways, as suggested), the usual way to address this in Windows is to open the file as delete-on-close, which deletes and unlinks the file automatically when the kernel File object is cleaned up (typically when the handle is closed, unless the handle was duplicated).  In the Windows C API, this is implemented by calling `CreateFileW` with at least `DELETE` access and the flag `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`. I don't know "go", but maybe it provides an idiomatic way to access this feature.

Comment: @eryksun thank you. I was looking for it in Go but didn’t find a straight forward way of doing it. But I saw this which I think should work, https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/?GOOS=windows&GOARCH=amd64#CreateFile